# Looking for raw interferogram data / raw FID data from FT-IR / FT-NIR / FT-NMR

Tags: fourier-transform, spectroscopy, mass-spectrometry, raman-spectroscopy

I'm trying to get my hands on some raw interferogram data / raw FID data from an FT-IR / FT-NIR / FT-NMR so I can run some tests using FFT with it (it needs to be real data). Here's a picture below of the data I'm looking for **highlighted in yellow**.  I'm looking for Alkali metals (Sodium, Potassium, but also Magnesium, Gold, Silver, Platinum and Palladium).  Any ideas where I can get these or if someone can send them to me as a text/data file?  I've searched NIST but everything is already converted

[image]

Comment: Have you searched scholarly journals for people publishing data on the alkali metals? Most scientists do not really have problems with giving out data like that.

Comment: @Kyle Kanos I've searched NIST but everything is already converted.  Which journals are you referring to?  I'm looking for raw data as a text/data file not just an image of the data

Comment: I presume NIST converted their interferogram data into a spectra, just ask if they still have that data. And I'm referring to whatever ones are the top ones in the field (I'm not an FTIR guy), I assumed you would know what ones would be relevant.

Comment: Why not just generate some artificial spectra (using `R` or Matlab or similar tools)?  It's not that difficult to create a few frequencies, sum them together, and then run an FFT on the dataset.

Comment: @Carl Witthoft I need real data.